# pandas.DataFrame.groupby(): keep 'whole' when grouping, in addition to groups

Tags: python, pandas

I want to produce an aggregation along a certain criterion, but also need a row with the same aggregation applied to the non-aggregated dataframe.

When using `customers.groupby('year').size()`, is there a way to keep the total among the groups, in order to output something like the following?

```
year    customers
2011    3
2012    5
total   8
```

The only thing I could come up with so far is the following:

```
n_customers_per_year.loc['total'] = customers.size()
```

(`n_customers_per_year` is the dataframe aggregated by year. While this method is fairly straightforward for a single index, it seems to get messy when it has to be done on a multi-indexed aggregation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the pivot_table method has a 'totals' boolean argument. Have a [look](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.tools.pivot.pivot_table.html).

> margins : boolean, default False Add all row / columns (e.g. for
>   subtotal / grand totals)

Answer (score 0):

I agree that this would be a desirable feature, but I don't believe it is currently implemented.  Ideally, one would like to display an aggregation (e.g. sum) along one or more axis and or levels.

A workaround is to create a series that is the sum and then concatenate it to your DataFrame when delivering the data.